# Syslog-ng destination not working

Tags: rhel, syslog-ng

the default configuration in `syslog-ng` config file is working fine i.e the service is saving the incoming syslog events successfully. But when the `syslog-ng` config file is modified to save the syslog data in another location, the service is not saving the data in the old destination as well as in the new destination.

RHEL - 6.5

Below is the config file:

```
@version:3.2
# syslog-ng configuration file.
options {
flush_lines (0);
time_reopen (10);
log_fifo_size (1000);
long_hostnames (off);
use_dns (no);
use_fqdn (no);
create_dirs (yes);
keep_hostname (yes);
chain_hostnames(off);
dir_perm(0775);
perm(0775);
};

source s_sys {
file ("/proc/kmsg" program_override("kernel: "));
unix-stream ("/dev/log");
internal(); #
};

# Capture incoming events on port 514
source s_net{udp(port(514));};

# Specify the destinations
destination d_cons { file("/dev/console"); };
destination d_mesg { file("/var/log/$HOST/messages-$YEAR$MONTH$DAY"); };
destination d_auth { file("/var/log/$HOST/secure"); };
destination d_mail { file("/var/log/$HOST/maillog" flush_lines(10)); };
destination d_spol { file("/var/log/$HOST/spooler"); };
destination d_boot { file("/var/log/$HOST/boot.log"); };
destination d_cron { file("/var/log/$HOST/cron"); };
destination d_kern { file("/var/log/$HOST/kern"); };
#destination d_mlal { usertty("*"); };
#destination d_all { file("/var/log/$HOST/"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forget to set up the log block...
for example:

```
log { source(s_net); destination(d_cons); };
```

Comment: Hello Ferenc, thanks for the reply. I am pretty new to the unix environment. could you please fix the code I have posted with your piece of code so that I can try. I would like to forwarde the logs on /home directory.

Comment: You should add the following to your config:

`destination d_all_home { file("/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/$HOST/"); };
log { source(s_net); destination(d_all_home); };`